# What is the difference between `Home page / Archieves` and the page set as homepage?

Tags: homepage, plugin-jetpack, home-url, statistics

In the image below, I set the page `Welcome!` as my homepage. There is no link to that page, and there is only one way to go to the homepage: click on the banner. However, there is two different items referring to the homepage in the stat. Do you know what are the differences between them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

“Home page / Archives” stat doesn’t necessarily represent the number of views of a single page, although it might if your front page is a static page. The meaning of, and reason for, the designation was briefly addressed by staff member macmanx, shortly after WordPress evidently changed this stat from “Home page” to “Home page / Archives,” in an April 2012 topic titled “[My stats.](https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/my-stats/?replies=17)”. macmanx said,

> This is an intentional change. Date and category archive listings are actually counted the same as the Home Page when the home page is set to display posts.
>
> Therefore, what you originally saw for your Home Page total was a collection of Home Page views and Archive views, which is why we changed the title to the much more accurate “Home Page / Archives”.

Comment: but how can visitors visit the `Welcome` page when the only way to visit it is to click on the logo of the website to visit the homepage?